# laravel queues with connections

Tags: postgresql, laravel, heroku, connection, queue

what is the difference between using the queue listen with connection or without

```
php artisan queue:listen
php artisan queue:listen connection
```

and is there a way to reduce the connections made by the queue to 5 connections only

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think `connection` refers to the specific connection in your config file, so you could have multiple connections and specify the use of one when running the command. When running it without the specified connection it will use the default one. You'll find your connections in `config/queue.php`

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),

'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    // etc ...
];
```